# how to find .tpl file?

Tags: civicrm-home, core

I installed civicrm 5.7.2
I am trying to find a perticular tpl file related to new individual contact.When I trying to search it shows me 'no matches'.

[image]

I referred a civicrm documentation

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the tpl file which is used to build the html by viewing page source.

1. Go to **Administer menu > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling**, select **Yes** for *Enable Debugging*.
2. Visit the page/form you want to check which tpl file is invoked.
3. Right click >> View Page Source.
4. Ctrl + F to find **tpl**

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, I also followed same steps, but it shows me 'not matches'.

Comment: A crucial missing step is that debug mode must be turned on.  I'll edit this answer.

Comment: is it present in CiviCRM administer menu?